# Spam prevention tips for Postfix

Tags: postfix, spam

Without using SpamAssasin, or similar, what are your best tips for preventing spam.

Please try and provide config examples :D

Comment: A canonical question was asked : http://serverfault.com/questions/419407/fighting-spam-what-can-i-do-as-an-email-administrator-domain-owner-or-user

Answer (score 10):

I make use of:

- smtpd_recipient_restrictions
- DNS blacklists
- local blacklists
- header / body filters

Example:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,
        reject_invalid_hostname,
        reject_non_fqdn_hostname,
        reject_non_fqdn_sender,
        reject_non_fqdn_recipient,
        reject_unknown_sender_domain,
        reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
        reject_unauth_destination,
        check_policy_service unix:private/policy,
        reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org,
        reject_rbl_client psbl.surriel.com,
        reject_rbl_client dnsbl.sorbs.net,
        permit
```

The `reject_non_fqdn_hostname` option catches a lot of servers, but your mileage may very depending who you receive mail from.

Answer (score 4):

Use [SPF](http://www.openspf.org/), SpamAssassin, Razor, Pyzor, DCC, Graylist and use a setup like the other answer example:

> smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,
>           reject_invalid_hostname,
>           reject_non_fqdn_hostname,
>           reject_non_fqdn_sender,
>           reject_non_fqdn_recipient,
>           reject_unknown_sender_domain,
>           reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
>           reject_unauth_destination,
>           check_policy_service unix:private/policy,
>           reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org,
>           reject_rbl_client psbl.surriel.com,
>           reject_rbl_client dnsbl.sorbs.net,
>           permit

Answer (score 2):

Nice idea is to have two separate machines (physical or virtual) for incoming and internal/outgoing SMTP traffic. That way you can have more restrictions in place for outside messages, more strict spam/attachment control, and less restrictive rules for internal mail (for example you might consider larger message size on internal server).

Using greylisting (for example `postgrey`) can be an excellent idea, if you don't want to use SpamAssassin. Just put it high on `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` list, like that:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
        reject_unauth_pipelining,
        permit_mynetworks,
        permit_sasl_authenticated,
        # checks for known hostnames, addresses, clients
        check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:60000
```

And remember to change default delay time from 300 to something higher, preferably random (but not higher than 1200-1500). This way if a mail server is unknown to your SMTP, it will have to wait a couple of minutes before trying to deliver a message again, thus relieving your spam filter and greatly reducing UBE.

I also suggest acquiring good blacklist of popular spammer CIDR classes, filter out incoming server SMTP traffic (not client) from *ppp* or *dynamic* domains. That should help also.

Answer (score 2):

Check out http://www.gabacho-net.jp/en/anti-spam/anti-spam-system.html - its a set of regex block rules for Postfix that block a high-amount of dynamic IP addresses without catching too many legit servers.

I also run postgrey (http://postgrey.schweikert.ch/) which helps catch what the regex doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

My first line of defense is my firewall, and I put it to good use since it provides the highest ROI and is exceedingly simple to implement.  Since I do not wish to make my network accessible to the entire world, I unapologetically block most of it (your mileage may vary, obviously).  Next, replace Sendmail with Postfix -- yet another high-ROI modification. Finally, I used [Jim Seymore's Postfix Anti-UCE Cheatsheet](http://jimsun.linxnet.com/misc/postfix-anti-UCE.txt) (minus some RBL and other external UCE list sites) to choose what would work best for me.  I can count on one hand the number of daily UCE attempts to my mail server, and, along with some of cop1152's suggestions  (to which I would add **no domain catch-alls**), I average less than one successful delivery per **month**.

Answer (score -4):

to PREVENT spam..

Dont let your email address get out there.  Keep it off lists.  Dont use it to sign up for ANYTHING, use a throw-away for that.

If you see a forwared that has a thousand addresses visible DO NOT PASS IT ALONG.

Dont try to unsubscribe from SPAM using the link provided in the email.  These usually just verify your email you to a bot.

If you have placed a Craigslist ad and receive some spam because of it DO NOT REPLY TO IT.  The spam is likely being re-mailed from the craigslist reply-to address.  It will go away sooner or later.

If you are using Outlook, DO NOT OPEN spam email.  Opening these emails can activate a unique link that will verify your address to a bot.

Comment: I believe the OP asked about Postfix specifically.

Comment: wow, you -1'd a 6-month old question?...and not because it was an incorrect answer, but because it wasnt specific enough?  Nice.